# Creating traces of SPEC using pin

Tags: benchmarking, trace, cpu-architecture, intel-pin

I tried to create traces of spec2006 but don't know what program to pass in

```
pin -t obj-intel64/champsim_tracer.so -- <your program here>
```

there are lots of cpp files in just one int program like bzip2 and gcc.

Comment: I am using Champsim as  simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide executable file name as input.
E.g.,

pin -t obj-intel64/champsim_tracer.so -- gcc hello.c

or

pin -t obj-intel64/champsim_tracer.so -- bzip2 *input_file_name*